# Balancing a stick using two different designs and comparing both

Tags: design, control-system, stability, negative-feedback, state-space

I want to understand which feedback systems are in general preferred over another model (that I'm going to show in image),so first we take a example of a particular system (here stick at 90degree from horizontal at initial condition)and then try to understand same concept for a general system as well

Here is our system (image )[image]

And I want that it remains at 90 degree irrespective of whatever disturbance force is so basically I can say it's output reference would be v=0 or x=0(where v and x are velocity and displacement of centre of mass of stick)

Now I'm thinking about two different approach of modelling to achieve desired result

1st approach-

Going with basics of feedback which is based on reducing effect of disturbance (basically output) using feedback gain (k) to achieve output  approximately close to reference (desired output) .here(in image) is a block diagram of that feedback system
[image]

But to design this model we need to know about  one variable only and i.e k ,but for desired value of 'k' we need to know about state model of open system G .

Now 2nd approach-

So here I'm trying to reduce or even cancel the disturbance (D(s)) rather than it's effect because if disturbance becomes zero it's effect will also becomes zero so here I modelled a feedback system like this (image)[image]

Where k1 and k2 are proportionality​ constants and we have to design only a electrical system H(s) (which is inverse of mechanical system G) .And again for designing H(s) we need to know about state model of mechanical  system G and here we get v=0 mathematically and that is what we wanted to achieve.

So my question is

1. Is both models are good to achieve desired result for  this particular system

2.is second model can be considered as feedback model or not?

3.why feedback concept based on reducing effect of disturbance rather than reducing disturbance itself

4.which model(in above two)is in general preferred and why?

5.Or my assumption is wrong that for value of 'k' we need state model of G?

Comment: It's substantially unclear what you are asking here, but consider that if the input ultimately being compared is not the angle but something related to its derivative, then the system will be subject to slowly falling over without correction.  Many real world systems actually employ two nested loops, the inner for velocity (which might be built into the actuator system) and the outer for position.

Comment: Please let me know what question of mine is unclear ?I'll try to correct it if you suggest something and my question is basically about these two models that I mentioned ,what are the drawback of 2nd model over 1st

Comment: You cannot use an inverse model to determine state from its derivative, because you end up missing the constant of integration.  A loop which examines the derivative of a variable can mostly null the rate of change (eg, you can stop that stick from moving very much), but it can do nothing about cumulative error.  In real systems, error happens: if you want that stick to be vertical, you need something which examines the actual angle and will through either its proportional or integral term result in a correction being ultimately applied to restore it to a vertical position.

Comment: There have been many publications on controlling an inverted pendulum - I suggest you do some reading before diving in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 3. why feedback concept based on reducing effect of disturbance rather than reducing disturbance itself

1. It is difficult to measure the disturbance directly (exact value of force of the wind blowing on the vertical stick and gravitational force pulling the stick down). It easy to measure the effect (angle sensor in this example).
2. What we finally want to control is the angle in this case. not just the disturbance. *Even* if we perfectly cancelled the disturbance, the stick will still fall down if it had some initial velocity.

> 2. Is second model can be considered as feedback model or not?

System has force as input and angle as output. So the inverse system is effectively a (disturbance) force estimator of the original system. If the inverse model is not an exact inverse, the force estimate will not exactly cancel the actual force.

Yes, you are **measuring the output**, then using (what you think is) the inverse system, to estimate the force acting on the original system and you are **feeding it back** to cancel the disturbance force. But note that disturbance estimators *are* used; but not alone. They are used parallely with regular feedback. Integrator used in PID control is in fact a very crude form of disturbance estimator for many systems. It generates an estimate of slowly varying disturbances acting on the system.

> 1. Is both models are good to achieve desired result for this particular system

Not all systems can be inverted. Inverse of a system with a zero on the RHS will be unstable. Unstable inverse systems cannot be used in the feedback (to my knowledge).

> 4.which model(in above two)is in general preferred and why?

First method is usually used. See answer to #3 and #1 for reasons.

> 5.Or my assumption is wrong that for value of 'k' we need state model of G?

There are methods of calculating K where the system model G(s) is unknown. There are some auto-tuning methods used in process control where the gain is calculated in real time based on the system test inputs and corresponding outputs. <sub>I am not sure if those methods can be used for an unstable system like a vertical stick</sub>.

Comment: As mentioned in one of the comments there are parts of the question / diagrams which are not clear. I have made some assumptions while answering.

Comment: Thanks AJN for such a  good answers !Even I make some mistakes in my question still you answer it ,as you mentioned not all systems can be inverted ,        is that a reason when we design observers to get state variables from output using feedback loop rather than  cascading a  inverse system which directly  give state variables (or mathematically say something like C inverse matrix )?

Comment: Yes. Observers can be used in more situations AFAIK. But my knowledge is limited there.